# An Applescript for importing data into AccountEdge Pro has stopped working

Tags: applescript

An Applescript that has been working for a number of years has suddenly stopped working. I have recently updated my OS to Mojave from High Sierra but I get similar syntax error on another machine running High Sierra.

```
tell application "AccountEdge Pro v18"
    activate

    import one purchase of type service from alias "Macintosh HD:Exported Job Bags:Export file:Exported Purchase #" username "ian" password "" separated by commas first record is data duplicates are reject them
    set the clipboard to result as text
end tell
```

I now get a Syntax error "Expected end of line, etc. but found identifier" when it gets to the word "one" in the script

[image]

Comment: @Ianrenwick did you recently update the _AccountEdge_ software between the script working and breaking ?  Since the script is throwing the same error in both High Sierra _and_ Mojave, for once, it doesn't sound like the OS upgrade is to blame, which leaves the software itself that might have undergone a change during an update that either broke its own AppleScript **`import`** command, or re-defined its AppleScript terminology that perhaps now expects different syntax. Check the application's AppleScript dictionary to check. Otherwise, email the software developers and report the bug.

Comment: Thanks RobC, I have done as you suggested.
 
AccountEdge v17 and my current version of the AppleScript are the same:

import one purchase
of type service/‌item/‌professional/‌miscellaneous : type of purchases to import
from alias : file to import from
username text : username for company file
password text : password for company file
[separated by tabs/‌commas] : default is tabs
[first record is header/‌data] : default is header
[duplicates are reject them/‌add them] : default is reject them

I'm running it from within FileMaker so will check with a previous version of it.

Comment: Had a couple of additional thoughts: the file reference points to a file in a folder that's in the top level directory of your filesystem. Is this correct? Other than this being inadvisable generally, it may also cause problems for AppleScript, which has had a lot more security restrictions placed upon it recently by the OS, and this includes file access restrictions (mostly determined by sandboxing, but even non-sandboxed apps can no longer access certain system folders). I also notice the file name doesn't have an extension, which is very unusual for proprietary software. Is this correct?

Comment: The hashtag symbol in the file name is also peculiar. It gives me the impression that there ought to be a number after it, otherwise it's a pretty superfluous element to appear as a word on its own, and at the end of the file name. So, is this correct? Even if so, could you try changing the file name in Finder to remove the hashtag? Then make the appropriate change to the file reference in the script, and see if that compiles. There's an outside chance the AppleScript compiler has incorrectly parsed it as a comment marker, and ignored the rest of the line. Doubtful, but not impossible.

Comment: Hi RobC, Your observations about filenames and location were useful and got me testing a few options. As part of this I tried to compile the original AppleScript and it worked, i.e no Syntax Error. Haven't worked out what is different about today compared to the other day? I did  discover that the text file was set to export as comma separated. When changed to export as tab delimited the import worked when run as part of a FileMaker script. So have solved the problem but not sure about the original syntax error issue. Will look at revising a 19-year-old script using your suggestions!